# optimising loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am new to Python. I am trying to do the following loop and wonder if I am doing it the correct way or if there is a better (faster) way to do it. Briefly, i want to compute a series of conditional mean of a variable y. The conditions are created with regards to the x variables. For example, there are y x1 x2 x3 x4 in the df. the first set of conditions would be x1>x2 and x1x2, x1

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=100)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,10), index=dates,                     
columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ') )
df['y']=np.random.randn(100,1)

cols = list(df)
cols.insert(0, cols.pop(cols.index('y')))
df = df.loc[:, cols]

xlist = np.asarray(list(df.iloc[:,1:]))
xlist = pd.DataFrame(vlist, columns=['x'])

xcombo = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray(list(itertools.combinations(xlist['x'],     3))), columns=['x1','x2','x3'])
xcombo['stat'] = ""

for i, row in xcombo.iterrows():
    x1=(xcombo['x1'][i])
    x2=(xcombo['x2'][i])
    x3=(xcombo['x3'][i])
    # the following two lines (intends to) select subset of df meeting the         condition x1>x2 and x1<x3
    dfx = df[df[x1]>df[x2]]
    dfx = dfx[dfx[x1]<dfx[x3]] # df[df[x1]>df[x2] and df[x1]<df[x3]] doesn't work
    xcombo['stat'][i] = dfx['y'].mean() # store the mean value of y in the corresponding row
```

Comment: I think you will get more useful responses if you describe what it is that you want your code to do, instead of just pasting code.

Comment: Briefly, i want to compute a series of conditional mean of a variable y. The conditions are created with regards to the x variables. For example, there are y x1 x2 x3 x4 in the df. the first set of conditions would be x1>x2 and x1<x3, and the second set x1>x2, x1<x4, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertuples() method of pandas dataframe. It is much faster than iteritems() or iterrows().

Comment: thanks. how do i get the i in the above code when using itertuples?

Comment: Itertuples returns a named tuple and you can access the index by row.Index.